# Fitting Laplace distribution to data

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution

I want to fit laplace distrubution to data which density is given by formula:

[image]

As I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) good estimator for mu parameter is median, and for tau - mean deviation from the median.

So what I did:

```
set.seed(42)
# Create a vector for which Laplace distribution will be fitted
vec <- rexp(1000)
# Defining laplace distribution 
dlaplace <- function(x, mu, b) { 
  1/(2*b)*exp(-(abs(x - mu))/b)
}
#Estimating two parameters
mu <- median(vec)
tau <- mean(abs(vec-mu))
```

However now if we take a loot at histogram of this density fitted to our data we will end up with the image following:

```
library(ggplot2)
vals <- dlaplace(vec, mu, tau)
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(vals), binwidth = 3) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = 1:length(vec), y = vec))
```

[image]

Which suggests that it doesn't fit this distribution at all. My question is:

Is this so bad because it I randomized my vector from exponential distribution which is not Laplace, or I'm doing something incorrectly ?

Comment: Take a look at `hist(vals)`, and see if it matches your expectactions.

Comment: The AUC of a PDF is 1.  But you're plotting count rather than proportion on your y-axis, meaning that the histogram of your observed data has an AUC >> 1.  You have a scaling problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
vals <- dlaplace(vec, mu, tau)
df1 <- data.frame(vec, vals)

ggplot(df1, aes(vec)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), fill = "grey", binwidth = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = vals), color = "steelblue")
```